# Название ячейки совпадает с названием таблицы в JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть две таблицы: **clothes** и **user_clothes**. Запрос должен выбрать все вещи пользователя и названия вещей

```
$Sql = "SELECT `clothes`.`name` FROM `clothes` JOIN `user_clothes` ON `clothes`.`id` = `user_clothes`.`clothes` WHERE `user_id` = 1" ;
```

Но беда, в таблице user_clothes название ячейки с id вещи называется clothes, как и таблица clothes. Из-за этого запрос работает с ошибкой, как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит попробовать так:

```
$Sql = "SELECT `cts`.`name` FROM `clothes` `cts` JOIN `user_clothes` `us_cts` ON `cts`.`id` = `us_cts`.`clothes` WHERE `user_id` = 1" ;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!